# How to connect to Google Calendar API using a service account using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-calendar-api

How can I use google auth client using nodejs.

I checked many articles and client URL will provide a code data which I can use for getting client details. but how can i use service client for automatically authenticate on behalf of client.my primary need is to get google meet link and add to clients google calendar.

I was following this code. but is manual url authentication.

https://github.com/isuruhettiarachchi/ssd-oauth-assignment/blob/master/utils/google-util.js

Comment: Rather than some random github, have you tried googles own documentation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there is a way to grant my nodejs application access to my google calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60929631/is-there-is-a-way-to-grant-my-nodejs-application-access-to-my-google-calendar)

Comment: Check out Aurinko API. You can upload your service account key and then create 'managed accounts' that represent users using the service account: https://apirefs.aurinko.io/#tag/Managed-accounts/operation/upsertManagedAccount

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this make sure to configure domain wide delegation to the service account from your workspace account.

subject is the user on your domain you want the service account to impersonate.

```
let google = require('googleapis');
let privateKey = require("./privatekey.json");

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT({
       email: privateKey.client_email,
       key: privateKey.private_key,
       scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
       subject: 'user@domain.com'
    });

jwtClient.authorize(function (error, tokens) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  } 
  else {
    console.log("Successfully connected!");
  }
});
```

Comment: how can i use it to create event for individuals of other domain.

Comment: You  need the admin of that domain to configure domain wide delegation for your service account.  This will allow you to then access the users within that domain.