# Recieving 401 Unauthorized when trying to refresh Google Access token

Tags: java, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

Hi so I'm implementing a Java Gmail API on a web server, and when try refresh the access token using a refresh token I have stored on the db I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:326)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:346)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:577)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:494)
```

The code I use is:

```
InputStream in = GmailIntegration.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        Credential cred = new Credential.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setTransport(
                                                                HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                                                                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                                                                .setTokenServerUrl(
                                                                            new GenericUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"))
                                                                .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication(GoogleUtil.CLIENT_ID, GoogleUtil.CLIENT_SECRET))
                                                                .build()
                                                                .setRefreshToken(refreshToken);

        cred.refreshToken();
        return cred;
```

I did have this working using the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow but this code runs on a server so when this first runs it asks the user tho authenticate on a box they don't have access to.

And I have checked the scopes a few times and they look like they match up and we have a service account but I haven't used it since not all our users will be in our Gsuite account.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to use Oauth2 or service accounts? Sounds like you are mixing the two.

Comment: I'm using Oauth2, we have service accounts for internal stuff, but this feature is meant for external users

Comment: The library itself refreshes the access token as needed why exactly are you doing this?

Comment: I want to make sure it's refreshed,could manually refreshing the token be the issue?

Comment: Try doing a cred.getAccessToken()  does that work?

Comment: I just get a null from cred.getAccessToken()

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is here; the library automatically refreshes the access token. So, why are you trying to do this manually at all?

Comment: I'm only doing it manually because it's not working automatically

Comment: Check out setting up `offline access`, there's a section on it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815451/11551468)

Comment: It is set as offine

Comment: What does `cred.getRefreshToken()` return?

Comment: It returns a string that looks like what I'd expect, Access token returns null though and we get the 401 when we try refresh it.

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace when you get the 401?