# Google Refresh_token not generating Access Token once it expires. Refresh_token cannot create a new Access_token

Tags: google-sheets, access-token, refresh-token

I am trying to access google sheets using Java client Library. First time access token and refresh token are generated and stored in File.(`StoredCredential`). Once the access token expires new token is not generated with Refresh token. Please suggest what can be done.

Sample Code:

```java
 GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                 .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
```

Comment: Read the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815451/11551468) about using `offline access`.